# Simple way to perform various replacements of string in a txt and erase whitespaces with python

Tags: python, string

I would like to know how to write a code to open a txt file, make various replacements, and then erase all whitespaces (including newlines), and then save the file with the original name.

Comment: Sounds like fun!  Good luck

Comment: Have you tried looking up the Python documentation for:
- Opening, reading and saving txt files.
- String functions, including `strip()`, `replace()`.
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file read by Python into a variable we'll call strFile:

```
f = open(filename, 'r') #we're just reading it now, so we use mode 'r'
strFile = f.read()
f.close()
```

Now, do whatever replacements you want to do to strFile.

Then to remove whitespace & overwrite the file,

```
strFile = ''.join(strFile.split())
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(strFile)
f.close()
```

Doing it in 2 steps like this, you can print strFile to screen & inspect it before overwriting, in case your replacement code gives you trouble.